# Certificate expiration does not match validity period in template (Windows CA)

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, certificate, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services, bitlocker

I'm trying to request a new Bitlocker DRA certificate from my internal CA. The template is set to two years, as shown here [Template](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jj15S.png)

I'm trying to request a new certificate via the Certificates MMC via "Personal > Certificates > All Tasks > Request New Certificate". My two year Bitlocker DRA certificate appears with a 2 year validity period as depicted here. [Enrollment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P3BF6.png)

But when I approve the request the certificate is always only valid for 1 year
[Certificate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ak68.png)

Answer (score 2):

This is because the CA that is issuing the certificate has it's signing certificate set to expire 6/29/2020. The certificate cannot be issued with an expiration date past the issuing CA's certificate.

Comment: That's 100% correct, thank you!

Comment: No problem, glad I could help.

Answer (score 1):

If you run `certutil -getreg CA\ValidityPeriod` you will see "Years"

If you run `certutil -getreg CA\ValidityPeriodUnits` you will see the default value of 2

To increase this to ten years run  `certutil -setreg CA\ValidityPeriodUnits 10` and press ENTER.

Then run `restart-service certsvc` from an administrative Powershell console.